# Electron.js: how to create a separate download webContents.session for a window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, chromium

I have an Electron [file manager app](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager), which creates 2 windows for different purposes:

- `quickView` a renderer window used for previewing local files. It uses "will-download" listener for detecting unsupported files by preventing download.
- `main` the main renderer window. It uses "will-download" listener for downloading files.

Each with their own `will-download` listeners attached to their session. But for some reason the `quickView` listener overwrites the `main` listener.

##### Window 1

In the following line I'm creating a `will-download` listener for the "main" process. The purpose of this listener is to download files:

https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/55fd2462cf83898610883191807b7488fb5bdf89/src/utils/downloadManager.js#L133

```js
win.webContents.session.on('will-download', listener)
```

The `windows.main` parameter in the line below is the `win` reference in the line above:

https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/55fd2462cf83898610883191807b7488fb5bdf89/src/electronMain.js#L516

```js
const resultInfo = await downloadManager.download(windows.main, {
```

##### Window 2

In the following line I'm creating a `will-download` listener for the "quickView" window. The purpose of this listener is to detect unsupported files (which triggers download event in Chromium) and prevent the download event:

https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/55fd2462cf83898610883191807b7488fb5bdf89/src/electronMain.js#L232

```js
windows.quickViewWindow.webContents.session.once('will-download', _willDownloadHandler)
```

I haven't found another way to detect unsupported files, which is why I'm using a `will-download` event in the first place.

### Problem

For some reason the `will-download` handler of the `quickView` window overrides the handler of the `main`:

When I trigger the app update download event here (from the `main` process):

https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/55fd2462cf83898610883191807b7488fb5bdf89/src/electronMain.js#L516

```js
const resultInfo = await downloadManager.download(windows.main, {
```

It triggers the event handler of the `quickView` renderer window:

https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/55fd2462cf83898610883191807b7488fb5bdf89/src/electronMain.js#L241

```js
function _willDownloadHandler (event, item, webContents) {
  ...
  windows.main.webContents.send('load:webview::failed', {path: fileURL})
```

#### Partial fix

I partially fixed the problem in [this commit](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/commit/47ce65bdac78e5c9b17315f16623d40d81dcf1bb) by specifying a custom partition name for the session of the `quickView` window, so it doesn't use the default session and do not overwrite the `will-download` listener created by `main`:

##### Main process:

```js
windows.quickViewWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    partition: 'quickPreview',

...

windows.quickViewWindow.webContents.session.once(
  'will-download',
  (event, item, webContents) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    ...
  }
)
```

##### quickViewWindow.html:

```js
ipcRenderer.on('load:webview', (event, data) => {
  ...
  webviewNode.setAttribute('partition', 'quickPreview')
```

But this fix resulted in another problem:

- The quick view window stopped working in production build (perhaps it has something to do with the protocol not working with non default session partition)
- Setting a custom partition to a webview causes the Windows protocol link association pop up in production when the window containing this webview is created:

[image]

I think it might be caused by the custom `app://` protocol created by the [electron-builder-plugin](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder). It seems the pop up is triggered by the "app" link.

Or maybe it's happening because I'm setting the protocol incorrectly when I'm creating the window somewhere around this line:

https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/47ce65bdac78e5c9b17315f16623d40d81dcf1bb/src/electronMain.js#L203

### To reproduce:

1. Download the project

```
git clone https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager.git
cd sigma-file-manager
npm install
git checkout 47ce65b
npm run electron:build
```

2. Install the built app from `./dist_electron`
3. During the app launch you can see the pop up

##### Notes:

I just rolled back the 47ce65b commit and added some test values
so it's easier to debug

To switch to the latest commit and create the production build:

```
git checkout 5246252
npm run electron:build
```

All the `console.log()` inside `electronMain.js` are displayed in the terminal (command line) window (not the developer tools console).

To trigger quick view feature:

- Select any supported file (image/ text / etc) on the navigator page
- Press Space (the quick view window should open)

To trigger a download event, you can just open "Navigator" page and drag & drop any file (or website URL) from the internet. It will trigger the wrong will-download event handler (the handler of quickView window), and you should see the console message.

The quickView window containing this webview is created on `app.ready` event. When partition is specified, the pop up will appear right after the quickView window is created:

https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/47ce65bdac78e5c9b17315f16623d40d81dcf1bb/src/electronMain.js#L698

## UPDATE:

### Smaller reproduction example:

I was able to reproduce it with this code:

```js
let window1 = null
let window2 = null

electron.app.on('ready', async () => {
  createWindow1()
  createWindow2()

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('trigger window 1 download')
    window1.webContents.downloadURL('https://stackoverflow.com')
  }, 1000)
})


function createWindow2 () {
  window1.webContents.session.once('will-download', downloadHandler1)
  window2.webContents.session.once('will-download', downloadHandler2)
}

function createWindow1 () {
  window1 = new electron.BrowserWindow()
  window1.loadURL('app://./quickViewWindow.html')
  window1.webContents.session.once('will-download', downloadHandler1)
}

function createWindow2 () {
  window2 = new electron.BrowserWindow()
  window2.loadURL('app://./quickViewWindow.html')
  window2.webContents.session.once('will-download', downloadHandler2)
}

function downloadHandler1 (event, item, webContents) {
  console.log('window will-download handler 1')
}

function downloadHandler2 (event, item, webContents) {
  console.log('window will-download handler 2')
}
```

When the `setTimeout` runs, I see the following `console.log()` messages:

```
trigger window 1 download
window will-download handler 1
window will-download handler 2
```

As you can see from the log, the will-download event triggers event handlers of both windows

If I specify a separate partition for each window, the problem with shared event handlers gets resolved, but I get the 2nd problem mentioned above - the link association pop up on launch

```js
window1 = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    partition: 'partition1',
  }
})
window2 = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    partition: 'partition2',
  }
})
```

Comment: Basically you want to handle the same event from two processes? Why don't you use the `ipc.send()` to send message from the main process to the renderer process? This way you will handle the download in the main process and send a message with the required data to the renderer process inside the handler

Comment: @TasosBu well, I'm attaching separate `will-download` events to `windows.main` and to `windows.quickViewWindow` but for some reason, when the `will-download` event of  `windows.main` occures, it runs the event handler of the `windows.quickViewWindow` event listener. I don't know why the handler of the 2nd window overrides the event handler, of the 1st window. I fixed it by specifying a separate partition name for the 2nd window so they don't share the same webContents.session, but as I mentioned it caused another problem

Comment: Got it! What if in your Partial fix, instead of `windows.quickViewWindow.webContents.session.once` you do
`windows.quickViewWindow.webContents.session.fromPartition('quickPreview').on`? I think you need to specify to which session the handler will be attached

Comment: I believe this may cause the "Windows Store" window to pop up, because you attach a handler to a session event that does not exist. The event exists in your `quickPreview` session and it has no handler

Comment: @TasosBu thanks for the suggestion mate, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, the pop up still occurs in production build. I think it's something to do with the protocol. The app uses `app://` protocol by default. I tried specifying a custom one (which Electron forces you to do in order to open local files for security reasons), so I added this line in `./src/electronMain.js` on line 196: `productionPath = \`sigma-file-manager://${__static}/quickViewWindow.html\`` but now it's showing the Windows pop up saying I need an app to open "sigma-file-manager" link

Comment: Did you specify a protocol for both sessions?
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol#using-protocol-with-a-custom-partition-or-session
It sais that you need to specify the partition otherwise it will go to `defaultSesison`

Comment: @TasosBu I just tried adding `session.fromPartition...` to the other `will-download` listener but the problem still occurs. In addition to my previous comment, I also tried specifying the default `file:://` protocol in `./src/electronMain.js` on the line 196: `productionPath = \`file://${__static}/quickViewWindow.html\`` it fixes the problem with the pop up, but now the quickView window cannot display files, it throws an error: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` it seems that the protocol is causing the issue.

Comment: I don't have a lot of time to help you at the moment. I'll try and fix it locally and open a PR when possible!

Comment: @TasosBu thanks mate, you don't have to do it, but I'll really appreciate it if you manage to help me fix it. I just edited the post and added  "Notes" section (under the "To reproduce" section) to make the testing process clearer

Comment: @TasosBu I found a solution. Thanks for trying to help mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If that's a wrong way to do it, please someone let me know.

Here's how I fixed it:

#### Fix for the problem #1:

Set a custom partition name for the window, so it uses its own `webContents.session` instead of sharing the default one.

##### Main process:

```js
windows.quickViewWindow = new electron.BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    partition: 'quickView',

...

windows.quickViewWindow.webContents.session.once(
  'will-download',
  (event, item, webContents) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    ...
  }
)
```

##### quickViewWindow.html:

```js
ipcRenderer.on('load:webview', (event, data) => {
  ...
  webviewNode.setAttribute('partition', 'quickView')
```

#### Fix for the problem #2:

Set `file://` protocol in the production path for the window URL:

```js
productionPath = `file://${__static}/quickViewWindow.html`
```

Here's the commit: https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/commit/31208809cda7614a7c2f32237ae14f6c9c602f8f

Comment: we are doing something similar and using different partitions to get separate sessions (we show multiple browser windows). We actually set the partition on the webview directly when we create the WebviewTag